# Kepler Eclipse and WindowBuilder GWT

Tags: java, gwt, swt, toolkit

I have issues installing  Developer tools, Google plugin for eclipse[req], GWT Designer for GPE  and SDK from ...gle.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3. I have installed Kepler SR2.

I have tried updating the software within Eclipse and also through downloading locally.

How can I get GWT installation?  Are GWT under Window-builder and Google Web toolkit same? Actually, I want  a GUI editor for web application.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install a fresh copy of [Eclipse IDE Java EE Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php?release=kepler) and then install the plugin as you did in Eclipse (Help > Install new software) and you wouldn't have a problem.

The GWT plugin includes the GWT Designer for the graphic editing.

**EDIT**

In order to see if you have GWT Designer installed try:

> 1) Create a GWT project.
>
> 2) Right click on the src package and create a UiBinder file. That
>   will create two files : a Java file et an XML file.
>
> 3) Right click on the XML file :  Open With > WindowsBuilder Editor.

Comment: I am re-installing Eclipse Java EE developer ie Kepler SR2.02. But there was nothing wrong with it. It was fine with the SWT and WindowBuilder but GWT was not installed.

Comment: Is there any particular raison you're using SR2.02 ?

Comment: After reinstalling Kepler, I installed via Help new s/w, google plugins for eclipse 4.3, GWT desiner core,GWT designer Editor, GWT Designer GPE, Window Builder Core but it is still unable to show the GUI. Am I missing some other plugins?

Comment: Updated my unswer accordingly

Comment: on my Kepler, I dont see GWT under WindowBuilder like this:https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/tutorials/stockwatcher   I am trying to practise this. The tutorial says about Eclipse 3.7  but I have 4.3 installed.

Comment: After installing/updates I still dont get GWT wizard under WindowBuilder in Eclipse 4.3[Kepler]. Updates says i have already latest version of GWT but i dont see it. Though, I see google web application wizard and plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Before installing, you have to install in the fresh eclipse ide.

1. Help -> Eclipse Marketplace then search for 'Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3' and click install button
2. Don't check any GWT Designer. Should check all above them.
3. Help -> Install New Software... by input url at work with: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3
4. Check all GWT Designer and don't check any WindowBuilder because eclipse will select the lastest modules of windowbuilder from Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3. (In [3] its version is 1.6.0 but within google plugin is 1.6.1)
5. When you found the problem on GWT Designer, you have to change gwt sdk to version 2.5.1
6. Enjoy!!!

Q: Why don't I recommend you to choose gwt designer in google plugin?

A: It's not perfect designer if you would like to develop in the same past way (GWT 1.0). It's similar ASP.NET Web Form.

This is the GWT 2.0 development way: http://blog.sortedset.com/googles-app-engine-java/gwt-uibinder-helloworld-with-html/